# How to setup spring url mapping configuration for specific url

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a web application which has url as below:

Share module

- `/share/001.htm`
- `/share/002.htm`

Answer module

- `/answer/001.htm`
- `/answer/002.htm`

How can i config spring url mapping for above?

I try to use configruation as below:

```
<bean id="simpleUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">  
    <property name="mappings">  
        <props>                                 
            <!-- user -->
            <prop key="/share/*.htm">sharecontroller</prop> 
            <prop key="/answer/*.htm">usercontroller</prop> 
        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean> 

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">      
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>     
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>  
</bean>
```

Anyone can help me on this? thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) what is not working with your configuration?

Comment: 2) is there any reason why you do not use the @Controller annotation and use explicit xml mapping instead?

Comment: I dont' know how to use annotation to configure this, could you please give me an example for this?

Comment: I just want to change my web application url from /share?id=001 to /share/001.html , but i don't know how to set it up in Spring mapping.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to change my web application url from /share?id=001 to /share/001.html , but i don't know how to set it up in Spring mapping.

To do it in an easy way you will need Spring 3.0's Rest URI Templates support.

See this [Blog: REST in Spring 3: @MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) for an example.